# Released object crashes App -- problem with alloc/init memory management

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, memory-management, malloc

I have a flipView class that I allocate and initiate. But, when I release it the app crashes. If I don't release it, the app works fine, so it seems. The error message I receive when I release it is:

> Malloc - error for object: object pointer being freed was not allocated.

If you could please assist me, I would be grateful.

```
- (IBAction)showInfo {
    FlippedProduceView *flippedView = [[FlippedProduceView alloc]initWithIndexPath:index];

    flippedView.flipDelegate = self;

    flippedView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;

    [self presentModalViewController:flippedView animated:YES];

    //[flippedView release]; //******** Maybe A Memory Leak *********\\
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct to put the last line there, as when you pass "flippedView" in as the argument for "presentModalViewController" it retains "flippedView" internally (without you having to write any additional code).

Most functions in the Apple frameworks will retain an object if it seems like they logically should. If you are presenting a view controller, there are really no situations where you'd want to pass in a deallocated (or about to be deallocated) controller to be presented. The containing view controller you are presenting inside of will retain the sub-controller until it is dismissed.

So just so we're clear, here is the correct code (assuming no other unusual circumstances):

```
- (IBAction)showInfo {

// Here the retain count gets incremented to 1 (usually "alloc" or "copy" does that)
FlippedProduceView *flippedView = [[FlippedProduceView alloc]initWithIndexPath:index];

// Retain count is unchanged
flippedView.flipDelegate = self;

// Retain count is unchanged
flippedView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;

// Retain count is incremented again inside this method (to 2)
[self presentModalViewController:flippedView animated:YES];

// Retain count is decremented by 1 (back to 1)
[flippedView release]
}

// ... Other code

// Finally, whenever the view controller gets dismissed, it will be released again
// and the retain count will be 0, theoretically qualifying it for deallocation
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `presentModalViewController:` message should call `retain` on the `flippedView`. That will keep it from being deallocated until `presentModalViewController:`'s purpose for it is complete. You can then call `[flippedView release]` as you should at the end of this routine. Unless there is something else missing?

Comment: Thank you fbrereto for answering my question. I am a complete newbie and working on my first app. I am almost finished but this problem is holding me back. I don't understand how I would code the expression you mentioned. Would it be like this ?:  FlippedProduceView *fView = [[FlippedProduceView alloc]initWithIndexPath:index];
    [fView retain];
    fView.flipDelegate = self;
    
    fView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentModalViewController:fView animated:YES];
    NSLog(@"Retain Count fView:%d",[fView retainCount]);
    [fView release];

Comment: okay, would it look like this?                                    [self presentModalViewController:[fView retain] animated:YES];

Comment: Inside of `presentModalViewController` you would call `retain` on the view you receive. You would not need to call `retain` in `showInfo` as the alloc/init phase does that automatically for you. You can then call `release` from within `showInfo` and the object will still exist because it was retained by `presentModalViewController`.